# Does Vidalia Control Panel have hotkeys / shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tor

I cannot find any hotkeys for the [Vidalia Control Panel](https://www.torproject.org/projects/vidalia.html.en). For example I would like a hotkey for the New User Identity button.

Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only hotkeys or keyboard shortcuts only apply to the site.  See the [preferences](https://trac-vidalia.torproject.org/projects/vidalia/prefs/keybindings) article, and [TracAccessibility](https://trac-vidalia.torproject.org/projects/vidalia/wiki/TracAccessibility) for details.